# Copy / Paste w/ Formatting from single cell to merged cells

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, paste

I have an Excel sheet with multiple pages. One of two pages is a data tab and has a long list of names and then several columns of data. (Cells A1 - F1 are headers, A2-A20 are named, B2-F20 are different pieces of data regarding each name). The second page pulls specific data (index function) from the data tab.

I have bolded info on the data tab, and when you index something, you lose formatting. Normally, I could create a VBA code to copy/paste special into the format (to preserve the bolded words), but the nature of the formatting page means it *has to have* merged cells. I can copy/paste the info but it does not preserve the formatting. If I try to paste special, I get the error "This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized".

Is there a way to paste and preserve the bolded text without unmerging the formatted sheet?

Comment: Is Bold the only thing you worry about?

Comment: Yep, Bold is the only formatting thing I need to transfer over

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Font.FontStyle = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Font.FontStyle
```

This will transfer the font style to the from the data cell to the target cell, regardless if the cell is merged or not.

Comment: So the only tricky part, is to distinguish what data is pulled up on the formatted sheet, there is an index function that will look at the title (I change the title) and search for the information based on that title change. Do you know if this will still work?

Comment: Yup, you just need to know the cell with the data and the cell upper left cell of the merged cell.  If you get stuck getting the cell ask a new question with the code you are trying.

Comment: Thank you, I will let you know in a bit.